# pip install ignores subfolder that setup.py install doesn't

Tags: python, pip, package

My package has a folder structure like so:

```
package
    __init__.py
    test.py
    subpackage
        __init__.py
        sub1.py
        sub2.py
setup.py
```

where `subpackage/__init__.py` contains:

```
__all__ = ['sub1', 'sub2']
from .sub1 import *
from .sub2 import *
```

the desired functionality would be to import the subpackage as specified below and have access to all the functions defined in sub1.py and sub2.py under the subpackage namespace:

```
from package import subpackage
subpackage.function1() # function1 would be defined in sub1.py
```

When I use `python setup.py install` this approach works. However, when I `pip install git+htpps....@dev` I'm getting this error:

```
from package import subpackage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'subpackage' from 'package' (/Users/..../site-packages/package/__init__.py)
```

and when I go to site packages, my subpackage dir isn't even there.

Why isn't pip installing my subpackage dir but setup.py install is? is this the correct way to reach my desired functionality? subpackage was previously a module, but has been broken into several modules for maintenance but want to keep backwards compatibility for importing them.

EDIT: here's setup.py

```
import os.path
from setuptools import setup

# The directory containing this file
HERE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# The text of the README file
with open(os.path.join(HERE, "README.md")) as fid:
    README = fid.read()

# Required dependencies
dependencies = ['google-cloud-bigquery >= 1.6.1',
                'google-cloud-storage >= 1.14.0',
                'googlemaps >= 3.0.2',
                'pandas >= 0.23.4',
                'patool >= 1.12',
                'requests >= 2.22.0',
                'teradatasql',
                'numpy',
                'scikit-learn',
                'scipy',
                'sparse_dot_topn',
                'strsim',
                'python-Levenshtein',
                'tqdm',
                'xlrd'
                ]

# This call to setup() does all the work
setup(
    name="package",
    version="1.1.2",
    description="package desc",
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="http://...",
    author="Me",
    author_email="me",
    license="license",
    packages=["package"],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=dependencies
)
```

Comment: Please show your `setup.py` or a [mcve].

Comment: I've included it in my recent edit

Comment: You must list all subpackages. Either `packages=["package", "package.subpackage"],` or `packages=find_packages(".")`

Comment: I added that as you specified, now I can `from package import subpackage` but if I run `subpackage.__file__` it prints out `/..../site_packages/package/subpackage.py` which is what `sub1.py` used to be. All of the `sub1.py` functions are there, but I'm missing my `sub2.py` functions which were added.

EDIT: I'm using new conda environments to pip install, and I'm installing from a git repo I've confirmed is up to date.

Comment: UPDATE: `packages=find_packages(".")` worked! thank you @phd. If you put it as the answer I can accept.